# symbolic solution of 6 equations and 6 unknowns with sympy

Tags: sympy, symbolic-math

I'm trying to use sympy.solve() to solve a system of questions with 6 equations and 6 unknowns:

```
import sympy as sp

S11A,S21A,S22A = sp.symbols('S11A S21A S22A')
S11B,S21B,S22B = sp.symbols('S11B S21B S22B')
s11,s21,s31,s22,s31,s32,s33,G3 = sp.symbols('s11 s21 s31 s22 s31 s32 s33 G3')

eq1 = S11A - s11 + s31*G3*s31/(1-s33*G3)
eq2 = S22A - s22 + s32*G3*s32/(1-s22*G3)
eq3 = S21A - s21 + s31*G3*s32/(1-s33*G3)
eq5 = S11B - s11 + s21*G3*s21/(1-s22*G3)
eq6 = S22B - s33 + s32*G3*s32/(1-s33*G3)
eq7 = S21B - s31 + s21*G3*s32/(1-s22*G3)

soln = sp.solve([eq1,eq2,eq3,eq5,eq6,eq7],(s11,s31,s33,s22,s32,s21))
```

However, after several hours the computer is still working on the solution. Perhaps it is too complex?

Comment: Why is symbol `s31` defined twice? Where is `eq4`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, even judicious solving of the equations cannot escape the symbolic explosion that eventually occurs with the attendant high-order equation to solve at the end. For example, you can solve eq1, eq2 and eq5 for s11, s21, and s31, respectively -- they are linear -- and substitute those solutions into the remaining equations. There are two that are quadratic but when they are substituted into the remaining equation there is nothing more that can be done. The expression doesn't simplify and you are left with a very large and unwieldy equation that has many radicals which, even if removed, would leave you with a high order equation that does not permit a general solution.

In these cases it is much better to plug in the known values and work with the 6 equations in only 6 variables.